# PHP Long/Lat Distance Function within a function calling out an API

Tags: php, api, coordinates, distance

To preface: I'm not the best at this so excuse me if I' overlooking something elementary.

I am using an API to pull in business data for "nearby places", and I want to use a distance function within it to be able to calculate the distance in miles (using coordinates of each).

Stand alone, each works fine, but when I try to embed the distance calculator into the API request, something is going wrong.

**For example, this works just fine (coordinates are hard coded here):**

```
<?php
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
}
echo distance($latitude, $longitude, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
?>
```

Now, `$latitude` and `$longitude` pull in long/lat of business A, and above, I have hard coded some coordinates here just to test that it calcs distance against. This works.

When I try to plop this code into a script which is pulling "nearby" businesses from an API (where I am able to pull coordinates without problems), I'm running into problems.

How can I run a function within a function so I can pull the coordinates of the nearby businesses and put them into the above (where I have the hard coded numbers)?

**Edit: Here is the code I am trying to put the code above inside... I would like to use the above function right before where it says "Deal Via" below - to show how far away the business is in miles**

```
<?php
if  (! in_array('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {
    die("Curl Extension is not loaded");
}

$key = 'REMOVED FOR EXAMPLE';

$search = "http://api.yipit.com/v1/deals/?key=$key&lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&radius=10";

$search_init = curl_init();
curl_setopt($search_init, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:' ) );
curl_setopt($search_init, CURLOPT_URL, $search);
curl_setopt($search_init, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$yipit = curl_exec($search_init);

$obj = json_decode($yipit, true);


if (isset($obj["response"]["deals"])) {
    $cnt = count($obj["response"]["deals"]);

    for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++) {
        echo "<p>

<h3>".$obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["business"]["name"]." - ".$obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["price"]["formatted"]." for ".$obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["yipit_title"]." (".$obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["value"]["formatted"]." Value)</h3><br>

<img src=".$obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["images"]["image_small"].">

    <b></b><br>
    Deal via ".$obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["source"]["name"]."<br>
    Expires: ".$obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["end_date"]."<br>
    <h3><a href=". $obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["url"].">See more information on this deal</a></h3><br>
    </p><br><br> ";
    }
} else {
    var_dump($yipit);
}

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? Rather, what *code* have you tried that hasn't worked so far? The working code provides only half of the story.

Comment: I tried putting that whole piece of code above into another function (the one calling out the API) encapsulated with <?php... I get a syntax error... I can call out coordinates from both the business on my site and the nearby businesses from the API. It's when I try to call them out within the code above, something breaks.

Comment: Can you edit the broken code into your question?  Remember, it's very hard to help if we can't *see* the code.

Comment: Added above - trying to use the code in the first block and put it inside the second block.

Comment: Almost there.  Can we get a `var_dump` of an example `$obj["response"]["deals"][$i]`?  The thing missing is the actual lat/long that you need to measure against.

Comment: Ah yes, I can pull coordinates with this line: `".$obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["division"]["lon"]."` and `".$obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["division"]["lat"]."`

Comment: Okay, so inside the loop, what happens when you call `distance($latitude, $longitude, $obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["division"]["lat"], $obj["response"]["deals"][$i]["division"]["lon"])`?  I see no reason that this should not work.

Comment: I'll give that a try shortly, but before I do (and set myself up for failure), I think part of my question is, I don't know where to physically place the block of code within the other block of code within the `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: Same problem - it's a matter of being able to put the line of code you wrote in a separate script encapsulated by <?php (same page in the php file). Since "distance" is not defined in the script that calls out the api, it's not working.